# How to make a dropdown in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make a autocomplete dropdown for my swiftui app. Any suggestions on how to make that happen? I want it to be attatched to a text field so when I start typing options appear below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:
https://github.com/simonloewe/TextFieldInputPrediction

You can give it the values and when typing it gives you the predictions back.

Comment: Thanks! that was really helpful.